# How would you simulate typing via Jest and Vue-Test-Utils?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

For my test, I am expecting it to start with a value of length 39 (maxlength: 40), and when I press a key (ie: 'a'), the length should then be 40. However, anything I try or look up doesn't seem to allow me to trigger a keypress/keydown/keyup event.

My Component:

```html
<q-input
  v-model="name"
  class="my-class"
  maxlength="40"
\>
```

My Test:

```js
it('Input should change', async() => {
  let wrapper = mount(Component, { name: 'M'.repeat(39) })
  let name = wrapper.find('.my-class')
  console.log(name.vm.$options.propsData.value) // prints 39 M's as expected
  name.trigger('click') // I try clicking the input. I've also tried triggering 'focus'
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() // I've also tried with and without this
  // I've also tried await name.vm.$nextTick()
  name.trigger('keydown', { key: 'a' }) // According to their testing docs, this should press 'a'
  // I've also tried name.trigger('keyup', { key: 'a' })
  // and name.trigger('keypress', { key: 'a' })
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
  console.log(name.vm.$options.propsData.value) // prints 39 M's without the additional 'a'
  expect(name.vm.$options.propsData.value.length).toBe(40)
})
```

Comment: If q-input root tag is not an input tag then you should try to trigger click and key down on input and not on q-input root tag

Answer (score 5):

#### Why does not the value change after triggering `keydown`?

In short: you can't change the value of `input`/`texarea` with dispatching `KeyboardEvent` programmatically.

How actually do chars come into `input`? On MDN you can find the description of [Keyboardevent sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#keyboardevent_sequence) (assuming that `preventDefault` is not called):

> - A `keydown` event is first fired. If the key is held down further and the key produces a character key, then the event continues to be emitted in a platform implementation dependent interval and the `KeyboardEvent.repeat` read only property is set to true.
> - If the key produces a character key that would result in a character being inserted into possibly an `<input>`, `<textarea>` or an element with HTMLElement.contentEditable set to true, the `beforeinput` and `input` event types are fired in that order. Note that some other implementations may fire `keypress` event if supported. The events will be fired repeatedly while the key is held down.
> - A keyup event is fired once the key is released. This completes the process.

So, `keydown` leads to `input` event by default. But that is true only for [trusted events](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#trusted-events):

> Most untrusted events will not trigger default actions, with the exception of the `click` event... All other untrusted events behave as if the `preventDefault()` method had been called on that event.

Basically trusted events are those initiated by a user and untrusted events are initiated with a script. In most browsers, each event has an attribute [isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) indicating if the event is trusted or not.

#### And how to test `KeyboardEvent`s on `input`s then?

Well, it depends on what is going on in your `KeyboardEvent` handler. E.g. if you call `preventDefault` in certain conditions then you can check if it was called or not in a test using a spy. Here is an example with [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) as a spy and [chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) as assertion library.

```js
const myEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'a' })
sinon.spy(myEvent, 'preventDefault')
await wrapper.find('input').element.dispatchEvent(myEvent)
expect(myEvent.preventDefault.calledOnce).to.equal(true)
```

But sometimes you even don't need a `KeyboardEvent` handler. E.g. in your question you write about an `input` with maximum value length 40 characters. Actually you can just use `maxlength` HTML attribute for the `input` to prevent input of more than 40 characters. But just for a study example, we can just cut the value in input handler (it will control the length not only when a user types but also when a user copy-and-pastes a string):

```js
onInput (event) {
  event.target.value = event.target.value.substr(0, 40)
  ...
}
```

The test for this may look like this:

```js
 await wrapper.find('input').setValue('M'.repeat(41))
 expect(wrapper.find('input').element.value).to.equal('M'.repeat(40))
```

So here, we directly change the value of `input`, not by `KeyboardEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where `dialog` comes from, but should you not be searching for the element inside `wrapper`?

```
wrapper.find('.my-class')
```

Also most examples I see use `mount` instead of `factory`

```
const wrapper = mount(component)
```

Here is an example from the docs:

```js
it('Magic character "a" sets quantity to 13', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(QuantityComponent)
    wrapper.trigger('keydown', {
      key: 'a'
    })
    expect(wrapper.vm.quantity).toBe(13)
  })
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace dialog with wrapper when generalizing the code. Also, in my factory method, I return what mount returns with a few options attached. But yeah, the trigger('keydown') is not affecting the input field